# hole in drywall too big for old-construction electrical box - what to do?

Tags: electrical, drywall

We cut the holes in the drywall for the electrical outlet boxes too big and now the wings on the old-construction boxes can't clamp the wall.

What are my options?

We just finished painting yesterday after weeks of hanging, taping and sanding the drywall. I new this was going to be a problem but I pushed it aside and said I'll cross that bridge when we get there, but now I'm thinking that was a mistake..

Thanks!!

Comment: Patch and try again? Cut them even bigger, put in new-construction boxes, then patch drywall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They make various types of cut in boxes have you looked to see if a different type would work? And they make box clips just for oversize holes. If I get a chance I will try and find the manufacture of those clips but I know they make them because I have used them.

Just make sure the hole is not so big it can't be covered by the finish cover.

Comment: Yeah the covers are the most important concern. Do you want to have to use oversize covers in this area? Might be best to fix it right.

Comment: I think the normal size outlet covers will cover, probably just barely. I think that when she cut the holes in the drywall, she used an outlet box as the template, but she drew the line on the outside of the tabs on the top and bottom of the box, not the inside. An easy mistake to make

Answer (score 2):

Google "mansard straps". (Man I hope I got that right)  EDIT: I just Bing'ed "old work box strap". That had the results I was looking for.

They're still sold in lots of local hardware stores, I buy them frequently here in Virginia. The straps, used with a good oversized metal cover plate, will cover a multitude of sin.

Oh, forgot to mention - if you can't find the straps locally, just make them yourself with aluminum trimcoil or soupcans and a pair of tinsnips.

Keep that girl.